# Python - Selenium Locate elements by href

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to find (and click) specific pages for my Python program using selenium.

I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='text']")).click();
```

And

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("text")).click();
```

With `text` what I am searching for. These do not work with the error

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

I can only assume that it can't do find element because that's for Java, not Python.

The only distinguishing factor to the links on the website is the href attributes.

All the other tags have repeats. There is no way I can 100% guess the right link, so I additionally need the locator to be by partial text.

Is there anyway to start this? Could I use other programs? Has anybody successfully done this? I tried searching but nobody has even asked this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'text').click()
```

or

```
from selenium import webdriver
...
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("text").click()
```

**EDIT:** For partial text search on the href itself try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
...
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'text')]").click()
```

Sources:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/faq.html?highlight=click#how-to-auto-save-files-using-custom-firefox-profile

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-elements

Comment: Both of those do not work, the first one changed the webdriver which changed everything, and both do not search inside the href itself, just the text that contains the href.

Comment: That actually works! That you so much. I have been trying this for almost the entire day. For anybody reading - use his edit!